# Python Social Auth NotAllowedToDisconnect at /disconnect/facebook/1/

Tags: python, django, facebook, python-social-auth

I'm trying to use logout with Python Social Auth in a Django app, but I'm getting

```
NotAllowedToDisconnect at /disconnect/facebook/1/
```

These are my settings:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social.pipeline.mail.mail_validation',
    'social.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social.pipeline.user.user_details'
)



SOCIAL_AUTH_DISCONNECT_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.disconnect.allowed_to_disconnect',
    'social.pipeline.disconnect.get_entries',
    'social.pipeline.disconnect.revoke_tokens',
    'social.pipeline.disconnect.disconnect'
)
```

And this is the code I'm using on templates

```
{{ assoc.provider }} (<a href="{% url 'social:disconnect_individual' assoc.provider assoc.id %}" class="disconnect">Disconnect </a>)
```

Comment: Are you sure when a user logs out of one of his account, you want to disconnect all his social accounts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Provide a separate logout action to separate logout and disconnect.

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout as auth_logout

def logout(request):
    """Logs out user"""
    auth_logout(request)
    return render_to_response('home.html', {}, RequestContext(request))
```

Refer to the [Django example app](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-examples/tree/master/example-django) for a full example.

In your disconnect pipeline you have `social.pipeline.disconnect.allowed_to_disconnect`. This will verify that the user has a valid way to login after the current login method has been disconnected. This is handle by [allowed_to_disconnect](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django/blob/master/social_django/storage.py#L23).

To allow the user to diconnect and to avoid the `NotAllowedToDisconnect` remove the `social.pipeline.disconnect.allowed_to_disconnect` from your `SOCIAL_AUTH_DISCONNECT_PIPELINE`.

Comment: Given Django example app link is not working. Have you a new link?

Comment: working link for the django example app: https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-examples/tree/master/example-django