# Service Provider initiated Single Logout in Django

Tags: python, django, saml, saml-2.0, python-social-auth

I work on a project with SAML authentication implemented using [python-social-auth](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core). I am trying to implement a view that initiates Single Logout (i.e. logout from all Service providers and Identity provider) on Service provider side.

Currently, being logged in via SAML, I can access specific Identity provider page (ADFS, if that matters) and initiate Single Logout from there.

So at the end there should be two options for logout - Django normal logout and the view that initiates Single Logout.

I was able to extract `name_id` and `session_index`, and put it in `request.session` because, if I understand correctly, they are required for Single Logout.

Also, the code from https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core/issues/199 looks very similar to what I need, but I didn't manage to get solution with it. Particularly, I don't know where and how I should use `process_logout()`.

What is correct approach to this problem? Is the code by the link above related to my problem. And if so, should I add some more code to make it work?

Comment: You should show us the code you wrote for this, even if it's not working. Right now it's not possible to easily understand and reproduce your problem.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem?
I am stuck with the same situation.

Comment: Unfortunately, not yet

Comment: Were you able to resolve this one? there is no good documentation or help available on this one. I did configure slo_url, though request goes to /complete/saml/ url which kind of doesnt make sense. I am sure something is wrong with my configuration it self.

Comment: [Have you tried this?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40146377/5675325)